# How to display disappearing Pagination Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

[image]

Good day guys. I just wanna ask from you how can I make the pagination control box as shown in the image below appear.This will appear only when I hovered in the testimonial div. The control is along with the theme features(wordpress) and it seems it don't have the option to make it appear by default.  I tried to apply styles Opacity:1 and Visibility:visible but these didn't work. I think it is on the javascript and I don't know how to trace down its code. This is the link of the site is `http://67.222.16.144/~lasikoma/`.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey Jed, it appears that your image did not attach correctly. Could you supply us with a link to the reference image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
    .ether-ctrl-wrap {
        display: block !important;
    }
</style>
```

Add this style somewhere convenient.

Comment: Thank you arthur. That solved my problem. It needs two mins to accept your answer. :)